# How change tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

We have a project that demands an single page application. For the moment I have this HTML / carousel page to create questions. As you can see, there is no input at all. this must be made possible through javascript. with an `onclick` event **every H you see, has to be converted to an input tag when you click on the tag itself.**

Any help? I thought I had figured a way out, but it doesn't work

HTML:

```
  <div>
      <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
          <div style="height:10px;">
              <carousel interval="myInterval">
                  <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active" >
                  <div class="CreateSlideCss">
                    <h1>
                        <div class="CreationTitel">
                            Click om uw titel op te geven
                        </div>
                    </h1>
                    <h2>
                        <div class="CreationVraag"> 
                            Click om uw vraag in te voeren .
                        </div>
                    </h2>
                    <button class="CreationVraagBtn" >click voor uw type vraag te selecteren</button>
                    <h3>
                        <textarea class="CreationAntwoordTxt" >hier is de content van uw antwoorden</textarea>
                    </h3>
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </slide>
              </carousel>
          </div>
          <div class="row" >
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "button.CreationVraagBtn" ).click(function() {
    $( "div.CreationTitel" ).replaceWith( "<input value='" + "hallo" + "'></input>" );
});
```

Comment: You could make a hidden `<div>` and show() this once someone clicks the `h` tag.

Comment: You are using angularjs, you should add angularjs's tag. This is easily done with angularjs. All answers so far are not optimized because you're not mentioning that

Comment: @SeeSharp: I added the tag to the question after I saw some angular content in it, and added a angular option to my answer...

Comment: Downvoting because you have not mentioned AngularJS is not very constructive I might say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your click to this:

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').on('click', function(){
    $(this).html('<input type="text" />');
});
```

and more angular way, you can use this in your `directive`:

```
.directive('carousel', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
          angular.element(elem).find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').on('click', function(){
              $(this).html('<input type="text" />');
          });
       }
    };
});
```

As per docs:

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite.".

---

> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint.

[<sub>jqLite is already implemented in angular which has the most commonly used methods. if you load jQuery before angular then you will make use of fully functional jQuery methods.</sub>](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an id to the enclosing element, remove the current content, and insert your new node using the DOM API.

So for example, you give it the id `myId`, then you can do this:

```
var node = document.querySelector('#myId');
while (node.firstChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
var newNode = document.createElement('input');
// set up attributes
newNode.setAttribute('type', 'text');
newNode.setAttribute('value', 'hallo');
node.appendChild(newNode);
```

Or in a jQuery way:

```
$('#myId').empty();
$('#myId').append($('<input type="text" value="hallo"/>'));
```

Comment: Completely removing the element from the page? I'm not sure if that's what you want. You could just hide it. Also, you can just chain the `append` after the `empty`. Now, since the OP appears to be using AngularJS, you really don't want to be doing DOM manipulation "manually".

Comment: OP said he wants to change it, not hide it. Otherwise you are right.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple option would be to style an input with a placeholder to display like normal text would, as long as it has no focus:

```css
input{
  border:none;
  color:black;
}

input:focus{
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Click om uw titel op te geven"/>
```

You could also [style the placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css), if you wish.

---

And I see you're using AngularJS, that makes this a lot easier:

A toggle:

```
<div class="CreationTitel">
    <span ng-click="showTitleInput = !showTitleInput">Click om uw titel op te geven</span>
    <input type="text" ng-show="showTitleInput"/>
</div>
```

Or just a "show" element / button that disappears:

```
<div class="CreationTitel">
    <span ng-click="showTitleInput = true" ng-hide="showTitleInput">Click om uw titel op te geven</span>
    <input type="text" ng-show="showTitleInput"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter: Care to elaborate? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5').click(function() {
       $(this).replaceWith('<input>'+ this.innerHTML + '</input>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>text 1</hi>
  <h2>text 2</h2>
  <h1>text 3</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the H tag should intelligent enough to render an input . You can place a class like "renderinput" and then add data attributes like

```
<h1 class="renderinput" data-pickdata=".CreationTitel" data-placeusing="text"></h1>
```

and js code would look like :

```
      $(function () {
        $('.renderinput').on('click',function(){
          var $this = $(this);
        var input = $('<input></input>').attr({
        'type' : 'text'
          })
        .val($($this.data('pickdata'))[$this.data('placeusing')]());
        $this.replaceWith(input);
        });
});
```

this will make sure that you play only with html rather than touching js in case another H tag is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Script code must be placed inside the CarouselTag in order to make it work.

perhaps an expert can give a verry clear explanation for this. although this is a solution for some who would like the same approach